# Elixir - module GenServer.Behaviour could not be found

Tags: elixir

I am getting the error, module GenServer.Behaviour is not loaded and could not be found.

For the following script:

```
defmodule FridgeServer do
  use GenServer.Behaviour

  def init(items) do
    {:ok, items}
  end

  def handle_call({:store, item}, _from, items) do
    {:reply, :ok, [item | items]}
  end
end
```

I am following a tutorial on OTP and received the error when I ran tests for it. I am currently using Elixir -v 1.4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're following an extremely old tutorial. `GenServer.Behaviour` was deprecated in [0.14](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v0.14.0) and later removed [in June 2014](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/7de880495bf848b956c36104d82816ef6dee20a6) in favor of `GenServer`. If you change that line to `use GenServer`, your code should work.